# JQuery is trying to parse my HTML as if it was JSON

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have the following JQuery code that is executed when the user clicks on a button:

```
function addRow()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : "addReport/addRow",
        dataType: "html",
        success : function(data) {
            $("#reports").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It produces the following response:

```
<table id = "reports" border = "1" class = "multisubmit">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Partner</th>
        <th>Permission Group</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select  name = "report">
.........
```

With the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2499
Server: Jetty(9.4.30.v20200611)
```

It appears to work. A row is added to my table.  However, I get this error in my console:

```
VM1010:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 18
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:45)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.h (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
```

It appears that JQuery is trying to parse the HTML as JSON somewhere.

Comment: jQuery 1.8 is quite old - do you see the same error if updating to the last 1.x release (1.12.4)?

Comment: The `dataType` is html, and the `Content-Type` is text/html.  There isn't a reason why jQuery would parse this, specific, response as json.  The issue is probably else where.

Comment: Stange that you can say this `appears to work. A row is added to my table.` since the success callback would not add a row to the table, but squarely replace all table content with the response. -- What is that response... Can you console.log it?

Comment: Are there any other `ajax` calls besides that one? ... If so, maybe it's one of the others. What is at line `script.js:45` in the file?